# when submitting time from form remove the AM / PM from $_post

Tags: php

I have a form on my website which allows a user to select a time.

when the user posts the time - it is currently posting as `12:00 PM`

What is the best way to remove the PM or the AM from `$eventtime` and replace it with :00

I am using a timepicker jquery plugin, which automatically adds the AM / PM.

And my PHP converts the selected date and time into a timestamp.

My html element

```
<input type="text" id="booking-time1" name ="selectedtime" value="" />
```

PHP

```
$eventdate = $this->input->post('selecteddate');
$eventtime = $this->input->post('selectedtime');


$timestamp = strtotime(''.$eventdate.' '.$eventtime.'');
```

Comment: Why would you want to lose that data? It seems important to know if the time is AM or PM. Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace`.

```
$time = "12:00 PM";
$newTime = preg_replace('/ ?[AP]M$/', ':00', $time);
echo $newTime;
```

But as stated in the comments you are losing some information by doing that. You could also extract the AM/PM using a similar regular expression and `preg_match`

```
preg_match('/[AP]M$/', $time, $match);
var_dump($match);
```